# CursorAdapter java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

Tags: java, android

my project is always saying

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

and my project suddenly stop.

I did all possible solution like uninstalling the app, making change the column name of the id from **_ID** to **_id** in my table of database, adding space in **_id**, everything that i found in google I followed but it's not helping the problem.

here is my code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
  Cursor res = db.query("songs",null,null,null,null,null,"title");
        ClientCursorAdapter adapter = new ClientCursorAdapter(
                this, R.layout.row_layout, res, 0 );
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**ClientCursorAdapter.java**

```
class ClientCursorAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter {
    public ClientCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, cursor, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Title);
        name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));

        TextView phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Artist);
        phone.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("artist")));
    }
}
```

I use SQliteStudio to edit,update,create and delete the database. how can I solve that error?

**Edit:**

[this is my embed database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMrcx.png)

Comment: add you database create code.

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran my database is embed database so i dont have any create statement in my code. :-(

Comment: then check your embed database having "_id" which is primary and auto increment

Comment: my "_id" was already set into auto increment because my table has 700 rows then the value of "_id" on each row has incremented numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should show the a CREATE statement for table songs. It seems that there is no _id row

Comment: I don't have create statement in my code since Im using SQliteStudio to create a database,table and soon..

Comment: I mark this as correct because of you helping me to analyze the code.. by the way you are all correct.. my column id is not in lowercase..